# Add/Remove on Java Arraylist

Tags: java

I happen not to give any thoughts about this but I have been doing this for quite a while in a project that I am working on.

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List list = new ArrayList();
        list.add(new DumbBean("A"));
        list.add(new DumbBean("B"));
        list.add(new DumbBean("C"));
        System.out.println(list);

        list.add(1, new DumbBean("D"));

        System.out.println(list);

        list.remove(2);
        System.out.println(list);
    }
}
```

It actually works in my case.
I do a lot of insert/delete/add on a java arraylist.

I happen to think if I am overlooking something or is there a better alternative to this. (...another collection?)

Thanks

Comment: It depends what you're doing and how you're using the collection.

Comment: @Mark Estrada - You can use remove(object) method. In that case you have to override equals and hashCode method in DumbBean.

Answer (score 1):

If you find yourself appending to the end of the list a lot, I'd go with the ArrayList. If you find yourself inserting and removing in the middle, I'd go with a LinkedList.

If you deal with lists that are less than length 20, I'd forget about this entirely. Unless you have performance metrics that indicate this is a bottleneck for your program, this isn't even worth your time.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a good comparison of data structures:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_data_structures

It's good that you already know that you will have a lot of inserts and deletes as this will help you decide on which is better.  Remember, some structures you will need to search before deleting or inserting in place.